The board game from *The Book*
In The Book, a fictional “Guide to Rebuilding Civilization”, which freely mixes factual and imaginary concepts and objects, one double page is a devoted to a board game.
I have only access to the Italian translation; here the game is described on pages 372-3 and is called La griglia (literally, “The grid”). It is a 2-player game on a 5×8 board with ten tokens for each player, five initially on the board and five to be added in later moves. Enemy pieces are captured by creating a row of own pieces, that allows one to “shoot” at an enemy piece as far as the row is long (if I understand correctly). The goal is to be the first to take five enemy tokens.
Does anyone know more details about this game? Is it an existing game or was it invented for the book? (Of course, it has in any case elements of many historical board games.)

is this the game in question? https://howtorebuildcivilization.com/cdn/shop/files/10_642d4d84-4495-42de-9c45-ad434cfeca9f.png?v=1667567291

@KMR That looks like chess (it is actually even written there above the paragraph) and it is as well not a 5x8 board

@KMR Thanks, but not: it's a double page with a rectangular board displayed as if to play on it, with explanations and smaller drawings around it.
